# Adding size of files using shell script

Tags: shell-script, shell

I want to add and echo the sum of several files using shell script. How do I start?
I have a list of them like that:

```
$ stat /etc/*.conf | grep Size | cut -f4 -d' '
123
456
789
101112
```

Comment: you don't we simply use `du`?

Comment: @msp9011, `du` will calculate also subdirectories

Comment: @RomeoNinov here we are checking only files...`du -b /etc/*.conf`

Comment: @msp9011 Not if there is a directory matching the pattern. It's unlikely but not impossible.

Comment: @msp9011 due to block sizes, etc, disk usage is not the same as total file size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this …

```
total=0
for s in $(stat /etc/*.conf | grep Size | cut -f4 -d' '); do 
    total=$(expr $total + $s)
done
```

Comment: Thanks! and if I want to output it in a file I do:
```echo total  > my_file.txt```, right? And what if I want to output the errors too what do I do then?

Comment: Don't use grep or cut on stat output. stat has format flags (%s) for this

Comment: Also, 'Size' is likely to assume an English or "C " locale.

Answer (score 13):

Also something like can do the work (with `awk`)

```
stat -c "%s" /etc/*.conf|awk '{s+=$1} END {print s}'
```

Comment: It requires you know a little AWK syntax (which, on the whole, is graciously C-like), but AWK _is_ good at "sum up this column in this delimited file and print the total for me." Sometimes I forget. `:)`

Answer (score 12):

```
stat -c "%s" /etc/*.conf|paste -sd+|bc -l
```

Comment: Although effectively the same as @xenoid's solution, I prefer this because 1) less rigamarole with format strings and remembering to append the final "0"; and 2) while it costs a process, it hews closer to the "one thing well" philosophy. It's also a useful use of the (perhaps underappreciated) `paste` utility that can be applied to a larger class of problems: separating a bunch of stuff with a delimiter. Another example is "unwrapping" (removing the line breaks from) a text file: `paste -sd$' ' inputfile`.

Comment: @TheDudeAbides, all those things are true about awk. And it use one process less. And IMO is much more readable

Answer (score 10):

### With `bc`

```
{ stat -c '%s+\' /etc/*.conf ; echo 0 ; } | bc
```

- The `stat` format adds a `+` sign and a continuation character after each size
- a `0` is appended at the end to close the dangling final `+`

Answer (score 7):

The most straightforward way is to use `du -bc`:

```
$ du -bc /etc/*.conf
5139    /etc/man_db.conf
393     /etc/nsswitch.conf
5532    total
```

If you need to extract only the number of bytes, pipe the output to `awk`:

```
$ du -bc /etc/*.conf | awk 'END { print $1 }'
5532
```

Comment: Hope ... OP doesn't require the grand total size of all files...

Comment: Also note that this gives disk usage, not apparent sizes of the files. `--apparent-size` option may be needed to use apparent sizes.

Comment: @Ruslan The `awk` line also strips off the `total`

Comment: @Izkata oh, indeed, didn't notice this bit.