# Really weird ```du``` behaivour

Tags: shell-script, shell, size

I want to print the size of a file from some folder `/etc/*.conf` in this case.

When I use:

```
cd /etc

du -ch $(ls | grep .conf) | tail -1 | cut -f1
```

I get 120K.

When I use:

```
du -bch $(ls | grep .conf) | tail -1 | cut -f1
```

I get 46K. and this should be the same size but in bytes right? so it should be some kind of `120000`, right?

When i use:

```
du -bsh $(ls | grep .conf) | tail -1 | cut -f1
```

I get 1.3K, what is this man?

Comment: Why you do not use the answers from your previous question? https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/483135/adding-size-of-files-using-shell-script

Comment: @RomeoNinov it's not like that, if I use that I don't think it gives me the right size amount, and I need just an explanation here

Comment: This seems like http://xyproblem.info/ . Please create new question with the real problem, not the way you think you can resolve it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`du -hc` shows the size of the files as multiples of the block size of the filesystem, which is typically 4K. This is actual disk usage of the listed files. The `-h` option prints sizes using a human-readable format (K/M/G) and the `-c` option prints the grand total size at the end of the list.

```
[root@testvm1 etc]# du -hc *.conf
4.0K    asound.conf
4.0K    chrony.conf
4.0K    dracut.conf
....
4.0K    vconsole.conf
4.0K    yum.conf
104K    total
```

With `du -bch`, the `-b` parameter lists the file sizes in bytes. However, this option also implies the `--apparent-size` option, which shows the apparent sizes of files as opposed to their disk usage. This usually results in a lower total:

```
[root@testvm1 etc]# du -bch *.conf
55      asound.conf
1.1K    chrony.conf
1.3K    dracut.conf
....
41      vconsole.conf
970     yum.conf
32K     total
```

`du -sh` uses the `-s` option, which displays the total size for each argument. This option is typically used with directories. When used against a list of files, the `-s` option does not produce any special output. The output of your `du -bsh` command will most likely be the size of the last file in list.

---

The `-b` option is equivalent to `--apparent-size --block-size=1`. To use block-size calculations while keeping the unit as bytes, use only the `--block-size` option.

```
[root@testvm1 etc]# du --block-size=1 -c *.conf
4096    asound.conf
4096    chrony.conf
4096    dracut.conf
...
4096    vconsole.conf
4096    yum.conf
106496  total
```

Comment: I see and what do I do if I have to display du -hc in ```bytes```?

Comment: `du -bc` will show all of the file sizes and the grand total in bytes.

Comment: I want the rounded size, with ```hc``` in bytes, how can I do that

Comment: @C.Cristi Please see the edit.

Comment: It has nothing to do with rounding.  Haxiel, good edit! @Haxiel

Answer (score 1):

You should check the result of `du` without the `| tail -1 | cut -1`

(ignoring the -h option  which just add the k, M...)

(based on http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/du.1.html)

`-c` will print the disk usage of all files plus a total. note that depending of your filesystem format disk usage of a file will be bigger than its real size)

`-bc` will print the "real" size rather than the size its use on the disk.

`-bs` will only print the total "real" size of each file/folder given to `du`. Since you dive du each file it will calculate the size of each *.conf file and your last line is the size of the last *.conf file you've given him.

PS: you can probably do: `du -bch *.conf` rather than the grep on ls result.